# ERROR_INVALID_NAME when trying to move a file using MoveFile with C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, io

```
        wstring path = L"C:\\Users\\oneworduser\\Desktop\\trash";
        LPCWSTR origin = (path + L"\\" + files.at(i)).wstring::c_str();
        LPCWSTR destination = (path + L"\\" + extensions.at(i) + L"\\" + files.at(i)).wstring::c_str();
        //move file
        BOOL b = MoveFileW(origin, destination);
```

MoveFileW returns false.
files.at(i) is the `wstring` name of the current file.
extensions.at(i) is the subwstring that goes after the . in files.at(i). For example:
If `files.at(0)` is `mytext.txt`, `extensions.at(0)` is `txt`.
MoveFileW returns false and if I `GetLastError()` I get error 123 which is `ERROR_INVALID_NAME`.

Why can't I move the files?

Answer (score 5):

You have undefined behavior. `std::wstring::operator+` is returning a temporary value and `origin` and `destination` end up pointing to freed memory. If you'd looked at your program in a debugger you would almost certainly have seen this.

Change your code to:

```
wstring path = L"C:\\Users\\oneworduser\\Desktop\\trash";
wstring origin = path + L"\\" + files.at(i);
wstring destination = path + L"\\" + extensions.at(i) + L"\\" + files.at(i);
//move file
BOOL b = MoveFileW(origin.c_str(), destination.c_str());
```

Comment: Thank you very much, without this I wouldn't have finished this program.

Answer (score 0):

```
LPCWSTR origin = (path + L"\\" + files.at(i)).wstring::c_str();
```

This line will create a anonymous wstring object, pass the data pointer to 'origin'. After this line, anonymous object will be destructor , and make 'origin' point to the memory that be free already.